# Help cannot spread a long table across two pages in a in two columns page

Tags: longtable

I urgently need your help. I checked the whole TEX.StackExchange, but for last 4 hours could not solve anything. Please help :)

It is quite difficult to explain the question, so would better show it in a picture. In a two column page, I am trying to build a paper, which components, in the tex code, appear in a following order:

1. Text #1
2. Wide table #1 with many items
3. One-column short table #2
4. Wide table #3 with many items
5. Text #2

[image]

I need to get an output as such:
[image]

Comment: just move table2 forward in the file (so it will become table 1) and use `[htp]` so it has a chance of appearing mid-column, and as said before the question should have _code_ preferably a complete document that shows the problem.

Comment: Yeah, but I need to preserve the numbering in the caption, because first in the Text #1 I refer to the Table #1, then to the Table #2, then in the Text #2 to a Table #3. Frankly saying I tried so many codes simple table and longtables etc. The full code is here in the text file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/wa1gkdwpnilkgk9/code.txt

Comment: That is why you should never refer to table numbers explicitly sbut use \label and \ref so that when the tables are re-numbered references automatically keep the right number. If you really want the numbers to be out of order (which is _very_ unusual) just put \setcounter{table}{0} before the table ypu want to have number 1 (and similarly any other numbers you want to force) but readers will not be expecting tables numbered in that way.

Comment: Please don't link to external files (it makes a mess of the archive unless you will keep that dropbox link forever) make a small complete test document that shows the problem and paste it into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Never* do this in a LaTeX source:

> n the Table 3.

in LaTeX always do

```
n the Table \ref{somename}.
```

then do

```
 \caption{my table\label{somename}}
```

then whatever number latex gives the table will be used in the cross reference, and you won't want the `\setcounter` below to force the numbering out of order.

Please post complete documents as here: I don't think your readers will thank you for numbering the tables out of sequence (the point of numbering them is to help find them) but if you really want that, you can. This uses the sequence 2, 1, 3

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,a5paper]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\title{zzz}
\author{Yyy Yyy}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\def\a{One two three four five. }
\def\b{\a Six seven eight nine ten. \a\a\a\a}
\b\b\a\a\a\b\a\a
\setcounter{table}{1}
\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{zzzz}
\begin{tabular}{cc}a&b\\c&d\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\a\a\b\a

\onecolumn
\setcounter{table}{0}
\begin{longtable}{cc}
\caption{a table}\\
A&B\endfirsthead
\caption*{a table (continued)}\\
A&B\endhead
aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\
AAaa&bb\\aa&BBbb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\AAaa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\
aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\
Aaa&bb\\aa&BBbb\\aa&bb\\aa&bAb\\AAaa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\
aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\aa&bb\\
\end{longtable}
\setcounter{table}{2}
\begin{longtable}{cc}
\caption{another table}\\
X&Y\endfirsthead
\caption*{another table (continued)}\\
X&Y\endhead
xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\
XXxx&yy\\xx&YYyy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\XXxx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\
xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\
Xxx&yy\\xx&YYyy\\xx&yy\\xx&yXy\\XXxx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\
xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\xx&yy\\
\end{longtable}
\twocolumn
\b\b\b

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was preparing a conference paper, it worked perfectly. May God reward you with goodness.